# Is it "superior of" or "superior to"?

Tags: to-of

Is it "superior of" or "superior to"?

In a sentence:

> We conclude that our proposed model is *superior to* the base case.

or

> We conclude that our proposed model is *superior of* the base case.

Comment: I think this is General Reference for ELL. It should be on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The number of up votes to this question shows that there are many around here who are interested in knowing the answer! Suggesting migration to ELL.

Comment: Let's not treat this as GR, but off-topic, so it could be dealt with on ELL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When comparing two items, you should use *superior to*.

The phrase, *superior of* is used to describe a hierarchical relationship, and is synonymous with *superior over*. For example, Jane's boss is the *superior of* Jane.

Comment: And in the hierarchical relationship sense, *superior* is used as a noun.

Comment: @JamesJenneman Excellent point.

Comment: And of course you can also say, "*Our model is the superior **of** the two proposals*."